# Karma-coverage not recognizing branch test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

My karma-coverage report states that my 'else' branch is not covered in the below example, but it is tested. Any ideas why karma-coverage is not recognizing my test?

utilities.service.js:

```
function formatValue(value, form) {

  if (form === '2') {
    valueFormatted = twoDecimals(value);
  } else if (form === '4') {
    valueFormatted = fourDecimals(value);
  }

  return valueFormatted + '!';
}
```

utilitiesServiceSpec.js:

```
describe('format values', function() {
  var formattedValue;
  var value;
  var form;

  it('should format 2 decimal places', function() {
    value = 100;
    form = '2';
    formattedValue = utilitiesService.formatValue(value, form);
    expect(formattedValue).toEqual('100.00!');
  });

  it('should format 4 decimal places', function() {
    value = 100;
    form = '4';
    formattedValue = utilitiesService.formatValue(value, form);
    expect(formattedValue).toEqual('100.0000!');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually karma-coverage is correct. You missed to test the else branch.

```
describe( 'format values', function() {
var formattedValue;
var value;
var form;
// Will test if (form === '2')
it( 'should format 2 decimal places', function() {
    value = 100;
    form = '2';
    formattedValue = utilitiesService.formatValue( value, form );
    expect( formattedValue ).toEqual( '100.00!' );
} );

// Will test else if (form === '4')
it( 'should format 4 decimal places', function() {
    value = 100;
    form = '4';
    formattedValue = utilitiesService.formatValue( value, form );
    expect( formattedValue ).toEqual( '100.0000!' );
} );
//Will test else
it( 'should test if value should not be formatted to decimal if form is other than 2 and 4', function() {
    value = 100;
    form = '5';
    formattedValue = utilitiesService.formatValue( value, form );
    expect( formattedValue ).toEqual( '100!' );
} );} );
```

Considering your utilities.service.js to be

```
function formatValue( value, form ) {
var valueFormatted = value;
if ( form === '2' ) {
    valueFormatted = twoDecimals( value );
} else if ( form === '4' ) {
    valueFormatted = fourDecimals( value );
}

return valueFormatted + '!';}
```

or

```
function formatValue( value, form ) {
var valueFormatted;
if ( form === '2' ) {
    valueFormatted = twoDecimals( value );
} else if ( form === '4' ) {
    valueFormatted = fourDecimals( value );
} else {
    valueFormatted = value;
}

return valueFormatted + '!';}
```

Comment: Great catch, thank you! That `else if` was a mistake as there are only two possible values for form. Changing that to `else` got me to 100% coverage.

Comment: What if I do not have an `else`? My `branches` coverage is at 75% even though my `statement` coverage is at 100%. Is there a way to tell karma-coverage to not count that as a branch not taken?